# Create 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' oracle trigger in Spring Boot

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, triggers, ddl

I'm trying to create something like 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' trigger for oracle db, but I can work with the db **just** via my Spring Boot backend. My Spring Boot application has just db connection. From db I get (two) [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEcFr.png). And now, when I have the structures of the tables I want to deffine the trigger on BE with the effect to the db but don't know how.

The tables were create like this:

```
create table tab1(
pk int PRIMARY KEY,
aa int);

create table tab2(
pk int PRIMARY KEY,
tab1_pk int,
FOREIGN KEY(tab1_pk) REFERENCES tab1(pk));
```

I want to create this trigger:

```
create or replace trigger tab1_pkUpdate
    after update of pk on tab1
    for each row
 begin
    update tab2 s
    set s.tab1_pk = :new.pk
    where s.tab1_pk = :old.pk;
end;
/
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be disallowing updates of the pk column in table 1, if you aren't able to make any database changes.

Comment: I still can make CRUD operation, but I also want DDL (to create the trigger)

Comment: Note that the trigger you've posted doesn't work in general (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=regarding-on-update-cascade#15307096023873r).

Comment: @JustinCave you mean like just for tab1 and not any table or there can be some situation where it won't work well?

Comment: The article I linked to walks through some of the ways that this trigger will behave incorrectly and non-deterministically.  I'd strongly advise against a data model that tries to implement cascading updates-- that's a good indication that you need a different primary key.  But if you're going to implement cascading updates, you'd want to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I have resolved the issue

```
@Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbc;
```

```
String sql=" create or replace trigger tab1_pkUpdate \n" +
                "    after update of pk on tab1\n" +
                "    for each row\n" +
                " begin\n" +
                "    update tab2 s\n" +
                "    set s.tab1_pk = :new.pk\n" +
                "    where s.tab1_pk = :old.pk; \n" +
                " end;";

jdbc.update(sql);
```